# How do I add my Samsung laptop's volume keys?

Tags: keyboard, samsung, volume-control

I have a Samsung NP355V5C, and just installed Ubuntu Gnome. When I try to bind the volume keys, the keyboard settings do not recognise the keys. How do I restore these keys?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Usage:

`/usr/bin/pulseaudio-ctl mute`      #     will toggle status of mute

`/usr/bin/pulseaudio-ctl up`        #     will increase vol by 5 %

`/usr/bin/pulseaudio-ctl down`      #     will decrease vol by 5 %